# Incorrect Syntax Near '='. [WindowsForm]

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I am trying to load data to ComboBox from SQL Server.

This is the method where the error occurs.

While debugged, this exception is caught after the following line:

```
metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.ValueMember = "[CD_Id]";
```

Not sure what went wrong. Please let me know the solution for this issue.

```
try
{
    string cDateFrom = DateTime.Parse(metroDateTimeCFrom.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    string cDateTo = DateTime.Parse(metroDateTimeCTo.Text).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    dbconnection.Open();
    DataTable dtName = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT CD_Id, CD_Customer_Name, CD_Effective_From, CD_Is_Active FROM ADM_Customer_Details WHERE CD_Is_Active = 1 AND CD_Effective_From BETWEEN @cDateFrom AND @cDateTo";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, dbconnection);
    com.Parameters.Add("@cDateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cDateFrom;
    com.Parameters.Add("@cDateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cDateTo;
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        dtName.Load(reader);
    }
    var listNames = CustomerName.ConvertDataTableToList<CustomerIdNameHolder>(dtName)
                 .Where(x => x.CD_Customer_Name == metroTextBoxFilterCName.Text).ToList();
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.DisplayMember = "[CD_Customer_Name]";
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.ValueMember = "[CD_Id]";
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.DataSource = listNames;
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
finally
{
    if (dbconnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        dbconnection.Close();
}
```

> **FOR YOUR REFERENCE**

Please have a reference of the following class files which involves with this code.

**Class File: CustomerName.cs**

```
public static class CustomerName
{
    private static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row, IList<PropertyInfo> properties) where T : new()
    {
        T item = new T();
        foreach (var property in properties)   
        {
            if (property.PropertyType == typeof(System.DayOfWeek))
            {
                DayOfWeek day = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), row[property.Name].ToString());
                property.SetValue(item, day, null);
            }
            else
            {
                property.SetValue(item, row[property.Name], null);
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
    public static List<T> ConvertDataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : new()
    {
        IList<PropertyInfo> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().ToList();
        List<T> result = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.Rows)
        {
            var item = CreateItemFromRow<T>((DataRow)row, properties);
            result.Add(item);
        }
        return result;
        //var customerName = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new CustomerName { Name = dataRow.Field<string>("SUQ_Question") }).ToList();
    }

}
```

**Class File: CustomerIdNameHolder**

```
class CustomerIdNameHolder
{
    public int CD_Id
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public string CD_Customer_Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

> **Project File Download**

If you consider for more details, please download the partial project source code [here](https://drive.google.com/a/ivymobility.com/file/d/0B_OZKvKL6wnCYWtCaDBQQXRRc1E/view?usp=sharing).

Please check in your system. I have enclosed both application(debugged)and SQL Scripts so that you encounter the same issue I have.

Please let me know if anyone fixes this issue.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Try removing the square brackets surrounding the column names in the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.

Comment: Note that you don't execute a reader.Read and then a DataTable.Load(reader) (unless you want to skip the first row returned from the DataTable rows)

Comment: @DanGuzman - I tried your suggestion. Still the same error.

Comment: @Steve - In debug mode, I traced the values of `listNames` has returned correctly. I also tried your suggestion - removed reader's Read() condition and passing directly to DataTable. Still the error remains same.

Comment: What is the datatype of the column CD_Is_Active?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce you error using your code and a fake table containing only the two fields and three rows. There is no error. So it seems that the error is not in the conversion of the table and the settings on the combobox but perhaps in the previous query. It is also important that you don't try to pass strings in the DateTime parameters but the DateTime variables. Your conversion could not be very well understood by your database if it is not following exactly your locale rules.

Comment: @Steve - Please try the source code in the link under the section `Project File Download` above. So you may encounter the same issue which I have. I have enclosed both application(debugged)and SQL Scripts so that you encounter the same issue I have. Please let me know if anyone fixes this issue.

Comment: @Steve - Please let me know your desired way(URL) where I can share the project to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the code shown but in the event handler

```
metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer_SelectedValueChanged
```

this event handler is called after you set the ValueMember or DisplayMember property in the code above. The first thing that code does is to try to select

```
string query = @"SELECT * FROM ADM_Customer_Details 
                WHERE CD_Is_Active=1 AND CD_Id = " + 
               metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.SelectedValue;
```

But at this point the SelectedValue of the metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer is null and this produces an incorrect sql string:

```
"SELECT * FROM ADM_Customer_Details WHERE CD_Is_Active=1 AND CD_Id = "
```

And correctly this is the cause of the **Incorrect Syntax Near "="**
(You can try this putting a breakpoint in that event handler to see the order of code events)

Just fix that code adding a test for null

```
private void metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.SelectedValue == null)
            return;
        ....
```

SIDE NOTE: Having looked at your code I really suggest you to remove that global connection with all the checks for open/close. The connection is a disposable object which contains **Unmanaged Resources** that should be kept for the minimum amount of time possible.
The coding pattern here is CREATE/OPEN/USE/CLOSE/DISPOSE and this is the scenario in which the [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) around a disposable object is mandatory

Comment: Thanks, Steve. I have now changed the Combobox's `SelectedValueChanged` event call from designer code to the button click event. Thus, this works properly. I would also change sql statements within using block. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues:

You should not use "[" and "]" when specifying property names for comboBox's Display and value members.

You may not use Readed.Read before loading the data into the DataTable.

```
    DateTime cDateFrom = DateTime.Parse(metroDateTimeCFrom.Text);
    DateTime cDateTo = DateTime.Parse(metroDateTimeCTo.Text);
    dbconnection.Open();
    DataTable dtName = new DataTable();
    string query = "SELECT CD_Id, CD_Customer_Name, CD_Effective_From, CD_Is_Active 
                    FROM ADM_Customer_Details WHERE CD_Is_Active = 1 AND CD_Effective_From 
                    BETWEEN @cDateFrom AND @cDateTo";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, dbconnection);
    com.Parameters.Add("@cDateFrom", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cDateFrom;
    com.Parameters.Add("@cDateTo", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = cDateTo;
    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    dtName.Load(reader);
    var listNames = CustomerName.ConvertDataTableToList<CustomerIdNameHolder>(dtName)
                 .Where(x => x.CD_Customer_Name == metroTextBoxFilterCName.Text).ToList();
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.DisplayMember = "CD_Customer_Name";
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.ValueMember = "CD_Id";
    metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.DataSource = listNames;
```

Comment: Hi, I tried without and with "[" ,"]" braces but the error still remains the same.

Comment: @Muruga check the update, you don't need to parse the date to string. Since you specified the date parameter.

Comment: Still the error is same. I verifed the results with SSMS and C# query. The list gets populated when I checked in debugging mode.

Comment: @Muruga where are you exactly getting the error ? At run-time or compile-time ? At which line ?

Comment: When I run the application, it occurs. On a button click event this code is written. While debugged, this exception is caught after the following line:
`metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer.ValueMember = "CD_Id";`

Comment: When you get the exception do you have already a value in the DataSource property or this is the first time that you initialize the  _metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer_?

Comment: Also can you try to explicitly declare the _listnames_ variable (IE use `List<CustomerIdNameHolder>` instead of var.

Comment: @Muruga Getting `Incorrect Syntax Near '='` at run-time is most probably an issue in the SQL query. But the place where you say you're getting the error makes it more difficult to detect.

Comment: @Steve - This is the first time I initialize the combobox `metroComboBoxFilterResultsCustomer`. I have updated all of my code which involves with this block. Please let me know if you need any other info.